# Stackdriver error reporting with gcloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-cloud-error-reporting

I'm retying to use the gcloud cli to send events to StackDriver Error Reporting.
The (very limited) documentation is here: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/error-reporting/events/report

Regardless of what I send as a message I seem to get this error:

> ERROR: (gcloud.beta.error-reporting.events.report) INVALID_ARGUMENT: ReportedErrorEvent.context must contain a location unless `message` contain an exception or stacktrace.

I have tried formatting the message as a JSON representation of an error report: https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/docs/formatting-error-messages
but the message seems to be the same.  Here's an example command and JSON:

```
gcloud beta error-reporting events report --service foo --message-file err.json

{
    "serviceContext": {
        "service": "foo"
    },
    "message": "Whoops!",
    "context": {
        "reportLocation": {
            "filePath": "/usr/local/bin/test",
            "lineNumber": 123,
            "functionName": "main"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gcloud --message or --message-field argument is just the `message` field of the reported error, not the entire JSON. Since you can't provide the `reportLocation` via gcloud, `message` has to be a stack trace or exception.

Using the [API explorer](https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.events/report) with the original request works. Logging the error also makes its way into Error Reporting via:

```
gcloud beta logging write --payload-type=json test-errors-log '
{
    "serviceContext": {
        "service": "foo"
    },                        
    "message": "Whoops!",
    "context": {
        "reportLocation": {
            "filePath": "/usr/local/bin/test",
            "lineNumber": 123,
            "functionName": "main"
        }
    }
}'
```

Answer (score 2):

Yet another way.

```sh
gcloud logging write --payload-type=json test-errors-log '
{
  "serviceContext": {"service": "foo"},                        
  "message": "message with stacktrace\n at /test.js"
}
'
```

```sh
gcloud logging write --payload-type=json test-errors-log '
{
  "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.devtools.clouderrorreporting.v1beta1.ReportedErrorEvent",
  "message": "message without stacktrace"
}
'
```

```sh
gcloud beta error-reporting events report --service foo --message 'message with stacktrace
at /test.js'
```

Comment: While this works, it would be nice to have an explanation as to why it does. Especially, because for gcloud you are using a trick: by specifying "at /test.js" in the message after a line-break, you can use any message. Even without a "real" stack-trace.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding httpRequest details under context.

You can find details of the json payload in the documentation.
The parent object in the json is [ErrorEvent](https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/reference/rest/v1beta1/ErrorEvent)

You can start from there and find links to its sub-elements [ServiceContext](https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/reference/rest/v1beta1/ServiceContext) and [ErrorContext](https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/reference/rest/v1beta1/ErrorContext)

Though I have not tried the command line option, I debugged the stackdriver logging classes which we use in our app, to find out what json payload we are sending and here is the sample json fired from our application.

```js
{
  "context": {
    "httpRequest": {
      "responseStatusCode": 500,
      "method": "GET",
      "url": "http://localhost:16500/product"
    },
    "user": "2247177"
  },
  "message": "org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException:  500 Server Error
  at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java: 94)
  ",
  "serviceContext": {
    "service": "cart",
    "version": ""
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

`gcloud beta error-reporting events report` requires stacktrace from programming language to report it. It is artificial (and actually quite stupid requirement).

Minimal Java like stacktrace:

```
gcloud beta error-reporting events report --verbosity=debug \
  --service test --service-version test1 \
  --message "at a()"
```

You can append interesting data if you keep `at<SP><CHARS>()` inside message on a separate line (thanks for Bash `$'\n'` magic!):

```
gcloud beta error-reporting events report --verbosity=debug \
  --service test --service-version test1 \
  --message $'Hello world!\nat a()'
```